# Baseless company ads

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

Apparently Zalando is baseless:

[image: Zalando SE based in]

If the information is not available, the *based in* part should not be visible.

Comment: These types of bugs bug me.  I'd think that the ad was shown to the company before it goes out into the "real-world".  Have the company page owners look at it and say yup everything looks good and only then should it become publicly visible.

Comment: Looks to me the real problem is that the company has too many bases.  The ad format does not exactly accommodate that.

Comment: Maybe it should just say, "Multiple locations" when that happens or, if possible, say, "Multiple locations in [state]/[province]/[country]" if the locations are all in the same region and "Multiple locations worldwide" if they're in multiple countries.

Comment: @BSMP It probably makes sense to say "Based in [location closest to me] and others" because I care about locations near me most. Just need to make sure you can see the complete list somewhere.

Comment: the best marketing text would perhaps be "based in ten locations, including _ _ blah and blah (one or two here, depending on how much room you want to use for the element) _ _"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out. This seems to be a bug in how we determine which office location to display on these ads. I'm looking into it right now and hopefully will have a fix shortly.

*EDIT*

This should be fixed now. Please let us know if you see anything like this pop up in the future, thanks!